# regular expression to match optional characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am struggling to find the regular expression which matches below 2 formats:

> cmd1 = "cmd:ifconfig:"PASS":"Fail":4:2"
>
> cmd2 = "cmd:ifconfig:"PASS""

Below is my sample python code

```py
import re
cmd_reg = r'cmd:(.*):\"(.*?)\"$'
result=re.findall(cmd_reg,cmd2)
print(result)      # output -> [('ifconfig', 'PASS')] Expectation [('ifconfig', 'PASS', 'FAIL', 4, 2)]
result=re.findall(cmd_reg,cmd1)
print(result)      # output -> [] Expectation :  [('ifconfig', 'PASS', '','','')]
```

But I couldn't figure out the regular expression which gives the output as mentioned in Expectation

Comment: What is `o/p` ?

Comment: Something like `r'cmd:([^:]*):"([^"]*)"(?::"[^"]*":(\d+):")?$'`? See https://regex101.com/r/woD4dU/1

Comment: i have updated i was referring o/p instead of output i updated

Answer (score 1):

Python’ regex package can’t match multiple occurrences of a given group, so this will fundamentally not work with a single regular expression (some other regex implementations *do* support this, by distinguishing between a match and a capture).

I believe your best bet is to

1. match the overall expression and capture the command and the remainder, and
2. iterate over the groups in the remainder using a second regex.

```
cmd_pattern = r'^cmd:([^:]+):(.*)$'
group_pattern = r'"?([^:"]+)"?' # or, simpler, r'[^:]+'; to retain quotes.

cmd, groups = re.match(cmd_pattern, cmd1).groups()
parsed_groups = re.findall(group_pattern, groups)
```

For `cmd2`, `parsed_groups` will be `['PASS']`, which I think makes more general sense than your desired result. If you need to fill the list with empty elements, you need to do this manually.

---

As an alternative, you could hard-code the four groups, and make them optional:

```
cmd_pattern = r'^cmd:([^:]+):([^:]+)(?::([^:]+))?(?::([^:]+))?(?::([^:]+))?'
re.match(cmd_pattern, cmd1).groups()
# ('ifconfig', '"PASS"', '"Fail"', '4', '2')

re.match(cmd_pattern, cmd2).groups()
# ('ifconfig', '"PASS"', None, None, None)
```

… I don’t recommend this. And this complex expression doesn’t even handle optional quotes yet, which would make it even more complex.

Answer (score 0):

in general there are a lot of ways to implement this. if you will give other examples the regex can be more fit to the general case (and not over-fit to this example).
I  searched exactly like you, and tried to search for any digit that between 2 delimiters of `:` which comes after 2 times of `"`, which all of this  extra string is optional)
try this:

```
cmd1 = 'cmd:ifconfig:"PASS":"":4:'

cmd2 = 'cmd:ifconfig:"PASS"'

import re
cmd_reg = r'cmd:(.*):\"(.*)(:\"\":(\d):)?$'
result=re.findall(cmd_reg,cmd2)
print(result)
#output -> [('ifconfig', 'PASS')]
result=re.findall(cmd_reg,cmd1)
print(result)
#output -> []
```

output:

```
[('ifconfig', 'PASS"', '', '')]
[('ifconfig:"PASS"', '":4:', '', '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd1 = 'cmd:ifconfig:"PASS":"":4:'

cmd2 = 'cmd:ifconfig:"PASS"'

import re
cmd_reg = r'cmd:(.*):\"(.*)(:\"\":(\d):)?$'
results =re.findall(cmd_reg,str([cmd1,cmd2])
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following pattern:

```
:(\w*):"?(\w*)"?:?"?(\w*)"?:?"?(\w*)"?:?"?(\w*)"?
```

You can try the above pattern interactively at the following website:

https://regex101.com/r/M9bf6m/2